# JavaScript preventing video controls from working on mobile

Tags: javascript, video, controls

I am not well-versed in JavaScript, so I did not really sure what I'm talking about. But I almost have my site exactly where I want it, but there is something preventing the video controls from working properly on mobile devices. I think it is a JavaScript, but I'm not sure. How do I figure out what is causing this and is it possible to prevent that script from running? I want to learn from this so if you could provide a lot of detail in your replies I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you in advance.

My site is https://www.enjoywithgusto.com/

Comment: works fine on android with chrome - just checked

Comment: Thanks. I was having trouble on iPhone. But maybe it's just me. I appreciate you getting back to me.